# QPainter issue in Qt HTML5 application

Tags: html, qt, segmentation-fault, qpainter

I have developed an HTML application using Qt 5.4.1. Application is running fine but after it runs for some period of time it is crashing. I used the debugger to see what is happening and could see that application stops execution after receiving SIGSEGV signal from the OS.  I am running the application on Ubuntu 14.04(32 bit). On the Qt console, it shows the following error: 'QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type :2
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::drawrects: Painter not active'
I am not using QPainter anywhere in my  source code. Could anyone guide me on how to deal with this error and the probable reasons for its occurrence

Comment: all gui elements (widgets) of qt have a paintevent. otherwise you wouldn't see anything. what paints is the qpainter.

Comment: Do you use `QImages` somewhere? Do you check if they are valid using their method `isNull()`?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I am not using QImages anywhere in my code. As I have mentioned the GUI is completely done on HTML 5.

Comment: Maybe you can give some more details. How do you use html5 in the qt application?

Comment: You have to build Qt from source, then build your application using it, then run it in the debugger. You'll see exactly where in Qt sources it crashes.

Comment: In Qt 4 , we have the option of developing HTML5 applications. I created my project under that category. Just like qml CPP interactions, here I have used JavaScript and CPP for the back end functionalities.

Comment: @Ober: it happens at the statement 'return app.exec()' in main.cpp where app is an object of QApplication.

Comment: @Gombat: I have developed the project in Qt4. Now I configured the same project on Qt 5.4.1

Comment: Did you write any QWidget class on your own? Debug the constructor, if it runs properly till the end

Comment: No. I do not have any QWidget class of my own.